# HTML Form with text input and file input not uploading to database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have a form with both text and file inputs and want to execute the `php` script with ajax (the `php` script works perfectly without `ajax`) cause i need the form to submit without page refresh. I have tried answers on SO but many didn't work. I tried [here](http://phppot.com/php/php-ajax-image-upload/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) and some others but to no avail. Below are my codes.

**The form**

```
<form action="genformexec.php" name="genreg" id="genreg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="logresult"></div>
      <label class="type" for="ccode">*Your confirmation code is the series of numbers sent to your mail after payment verification</label>
      <input class="half" type="text" name="ccode" id="ccode" placeholder="Confirmation Code">
      <input class="half" type="email" name="uemail" id="uemail" placeholder="Email Address">
      <input class="half" type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
      <input class="half" type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
      <input class="full" type="text" name="cname" id="cname" placeholder="Company Name">
      <input class="full" type="text" name="crcnum" id="crcnum" placeholder="Company RC/BN Number">
      <input class="full" type="text" name="uaddress" id="uaddress" placeholder="Residential Address">
      <input class="full" type="text" name="caddress" id="caddress" placeholder="Company Address">
      <textarea class="full" rows="7" name="briefdes" id="briefdes" placeholder="Brief description about your company"></textarea>
      <input class="half" type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username">
      <input class="half" type="text" name="uphone" id="uphone" placeholder="Phone Number">
      <input class="half" type="text" name="pword" id="pword" placeholder="Password">
      <input class="half" type="text" name="cfpword" id="cfpword" placeholder="Re-Type Password">
      <div class="profImage"><img id="logo_prev" src=""></div><br>
      <label for="profimages">Upload Company Logo/Profile Picture</label><br><br>
      <input type="file" onchange="logo_prev()" name="profimages" id="profimages">
      <div class="coverimage"><img id="cover_prev"src=""></div>
      <label for="coverimage">Upload a cover image for your profile</label><br><br>
      <input type="file" onchange="cover_prev()" name="coverimage" id="coverimage">
      <input type="file" name="profimages" id="profimages">
      <label class="type">Product/Commodity of Interest</label>
      <div class="postLimit">
      <p class="limitType">Agro Commodities</p>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Cashew"> Cashew</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Charcoal"> Charcoal</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Hibiscus"> Hibiscus</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Sesame seeds"> Sesame seeds</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Kolanut"> Kolanut</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Wonderful Kola"> Wonderful Kola</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Vegetables"> Vegetables</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Cocoa"> Cocoa</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Shea nut"> Shea nut</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Shea butter"> Shea butter</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Coco butter"> Coco butter</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Gum Arabic"> Gum Arabic</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Cassava"> Cassava</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Rubber"> Rubber</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Ginger"> Ginger</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Cotton"> Cotton</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Coconut"> Coconut</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Palm Kernel"> Palm Kernel</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Palm Oil"> Palm Oil</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Yam"> Yam</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Plantain"> Plantain</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Pepper"> Pepper</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Ground Nut"> Ground Nut</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Millet"> Millet</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Melon (Egusi)"> Melon (Egusi)</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Soybeans"> Soybeans</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Locust Beans"> Locust Beans</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Cashew, Soybeans, Locust Beans, Yam, Plantain, Pepper, Ground Nut, Millet, Melon (Egusi), Cashew Nuts, Palm Oil, Cotton, Coconuts, Palm Kernel Rubber, Ginger Charcoal, Hibiscus, Sesame seeds, Kolanut, Wonderful Kola, Vegetables, Cocoa, Shea nut, Shea butter, Coco butter, Gum Arabic, Cassava">All</div>
      </div>
      <div class="postLimit">
      <p class="limitType">Solid Minerals</p>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Barite"> Barite</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Bentonite"> Bentonite</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Bismuth"> Bismuth</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Bitumen"> Bitumen</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Cassiterite"> Cassiterite</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Clay"> Clay</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Coal"> Coal</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Columbite"> Columbite</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Feldspar"> Feldspar</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Fluorite"> Fluorite</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Gemstones"> Gemstones</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Gold"> Gold</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Gypsum"> Gypsum</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Kaolin"> Kaolin</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Lead ore"> Lead ore</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Limestone"> Limestone</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Manganese"> Manganese</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Mica"> Mica</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Molybdenum"> Molybdenum</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Rutile"> Rutile</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Silver"> Silver</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Talc"> Talc</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Tantalite"> Tantalite</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Wolframite"> Wolframite</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Zinc ore"> Zinc ore</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Zircon Sand"> Zircon Sand</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Barite, Bentonite, Bismuth, Bitumen, Cassiterite, Clay, Coal, Columbite, Feldspar, Fluorite, Gemstones, Gold, Gypsum, Kaolin, Lead ore, Gemstone, Manganese, Mica, Molybdenum, Rutile, Silver, Talc, Tantalite, Wolframite, Zinc ore, Zircon Sand">All</div>
      </div>
      <div class="postLimit">
      <p class="limitType">Manufactured Products</p>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Chemical and Pharmaceuticals">Chemical and Pharmaceuticals</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Domestic and Industrial Plastics and Rubber">Domestic and Industrial Plastics and Rubber</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Basic Metal, Iron and Steel and Fabricated Metal Products">Basic Metal, Iron and Steel and Fabricated Metal Products</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Pulp, Paper and Paper Products, Printing and Publishing">Pulp, Paper and Paper Products, Printing and Publishing</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Electrical and Electronics"> Electrical and Electronics</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Textile, Wearing Apparel, Carpet, Leather/Leather Footwear">Textile, Wearing Apparel, Carpet, Leather/Leather Footwear</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Wood and Wood Products Including Furniture">Wood and Wood Products Including Furniture</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Non-Metallic Mineral Products">Non-Metallic Mineral Products</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Motor Vehicle and Miscellaneous Assembly">Motor Vehicle and Miscellaneous Assembly</div>
      <div class="checkin"><input type="checkbox" name="postValue[]" value="Chemical and Pharmaceuticals, Domestic and Industrial Plastics and Rubber, Basic Metal, Iron and Steel and Fabricated Metal Products, Pulp, Paper and Paper Products, Printing and Publishing, Electrical and Electronics, Textile, Wearing Apparel, Carpet, Leather/Leather Footwear, Wood and Wood Products Including Furniture, Non-Metallic Mineral Products, Motor Vehicle and Miscellaneous Assembly">All</div>
      </div>
      <label class="type" for="regas">You are registering as:</label>
      <input type="text" class="full readonly" readonly name="regas" id="regas" value="Exporter">
      <label class="type" for="package">Package type:</label>
      <input type="text" class="full readonly" readonly name="package" id="package" value="Bronze">
      <input type="submit" name="regSubmit" id="regSubmit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

**The Ajax**

```
$('#genreg').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var ccode = $('#ccode').val();
  var fname = $('#fname').val();
  var lname = $('#lname').val();
  var cname = $('#cname').val();
  var crnum = $('#crcnum').val();
  var uaddress = $('#uaddress').val();
  var caddress = $('#caddress').val();
  var briefdes = $('#briefdes').val();
  var uname = $('#uname').val();
  var uphone = $('#uphone').val();
  var pword = $('#pword').val();
  var cfpword = $('#cfpword').val();
  var posttype = $("input[name=postValue]").each($(this)).val();
  $.ajax({
      url: "genformexec.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(data) {
          $('.logresult').html(data);
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
  return false;
```

});

**The PHP**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

if (isset($_POST['regSubmit']))
{
  $fname = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
  $lname = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
  $cname = strip_tags(@$_POST['cname']);
  $crnum = strip_tags(@$_POST['crcnum']);
  $uaddress = strip_tags(@$_POST['uaddress']);
  $caddress = strip_tags(@$_POST['caddress']);
  $briefdes = strip_tags(@$_POST['briefdes']);
  $uname = strip_tags(@$_POST['uname']);
  $uphone = strip_tags(@$_POST['uphone']);
  $pword = $_POST['pword'];
  $cfpword = $_POST['cfpword'];
  $uemail = $_POST['uemail'];
  $regas = strip_tags(@$_POST['regas']);
  $package = strip_tags(@$_POST['package']);
  $imagedir = './profimages/';
  $profimages = $_FILES['profimages']['name'];
  $profimagestmpname = $_FILES['profimages']['tmp_name'];
  $profimagesType = $_FILES['profimages']['type'];
  $profimagesSize = $_FILES['profimages']['size'];
  $regdate = date('d/m/Y');
  $ccode = strip_tags(@$_POST['ccode']);
  $posttype = join(", ", $_POST['postValue']);
  $status = "0";
  $verified = "0";
  $zero = "0";
  $website = strip_tags(@$_POST['website']);
  $coverimage = $_FILES['coverimage']['name'];
  $coverimagetmpname = $_FILES['coverimage']['tmp_name'];
  $coverimageSize = $_FILES['coverimage']['size'];
  $coverimageType = $_FILES['coverimage']['type'];

  $csql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM paymentverification WHERE code = $ccode";

  $psql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM paymentverification WHERE code = ?");

  $psql->bindParam(1, $ccode, SQLITE3_TEXT);

  $cret = $db->querySingle($csql);
  $pret = $psql->execute();

  if ($cret == 1)
  {
    while ($prow = $pret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $cpackage = $prow['package'];

      if ($cpackage == $package)
      {

      $cql = <<<EOF
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE ccode = $ccode;
EOF;

    $count = $db->querySingle($cql);

    if ($count == 1)
    {
      echo "This code as already been used";
    }
    else
    {
        if ($pword != $cfpword)
        {
          echo 'The passwords you entered do not match. Please try again!.';
        }
        else
        {
            if (strlen($pword) <= 8)
            {
                echo 'Your password must be more than 8 characters';
            }
            else
            {


                    $imagepath = $imagedir . $profimages;
                    $imagepath_2 = $imagedir . $coverimage;

                    $imageresult = move_uploaded_file($profimagestmpname, $imagepath);
                    $imageresult_2 = move_uploaded_file($coverimagetmpname, $imagepath_2);

                    if (!$imageresult && !$imageresult_2)
                    {
                      echo "Error uploading Company Logo/Profile Picture";
                    }
                    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                    {
                      $profimages = addslashes($profimages);
                      $imagepath = addslashes($imagepath);
                      $coverimage = addslashes($coverimage);
                      $imagepath_2 = addslashes($imagepath_2);
                    }

                    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, cname, crcnum, caddress, uaddress, briefdes, uemail, uphone, uname, regas, pword, cfpword, profimages, package, regdate, ccode, posttype, status, verified, website, coverimage)
                VALUES (:fname, :lname, :cname, :crnum, :caddress, :uaddress, :briefdes, :uemail, :uphone, :uname, :regas, :pword, :cfpword, :profimages, :package, :regdate, :ccode, :posttype, :status, :verified, :website, :coverimage)');

                    $stmt->bindValue(':fname', $fname, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':lname', $lname, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':cname', $cname, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':crnum', $crnum, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':caddress', $caddress, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':uaddress', $uaddress, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':briefdes', $briefdes, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':uemail', $uemail, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':uphone', $uphone, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':regas', $regas, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':regdate', $regdate, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':uname', $uname, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':pword', password_hash($pword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
                    $stmt->bindValue(':cfpword', password_hash($cfpword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
                    $stmt->bindValue(':profimages', $imagepath, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':package', $package, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':ccode', $ccode, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':posttype', $posttype, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':status', $status, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':verified', $verified, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':website', $website, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':coverimage', $imagepath_2, SQLITE3_TEXT);

                    $result = $stmt->execute();

                    if ($result)
                    {
                        echo "Account Successfully Created";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Sorry!.....There was an issue creating your account. Please try again";
                    }
              }
          }
        }
      }
        else
        {
            echo "You payed for the $cpackage package";
            exit();
        }
      }
  }
}
?>
```

When i say `console.log(something)` to check if the `ajax request` is sent, it logs but the data is just not submitted to the database. Thanks i would appreciate any relevant help.

Comment: Send data like this `$('#genreg').serialize()`

Comment: Thanks but Didn't work @MilanChheda

Comment: did you notice that you have two input files with the same id, same name?

Comment: as far as the ajax part is concerned I guess it works well, I don't know about the SQL part? you said it worked with direct php

Comment: Yes it is @user10089632 and i have removed the duplicate `file input` but didn't work

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: @WhiteHox have you tried the answers below?

Comment: Yes @MasivuyeCokile and its getting frustrating I can't seem to find why it works without ajax and won't work with ajax

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 <script>
$('#genreg').on('submit', function (e) {



  var formDat = new FormData($(this)[0]);    



  $.ajax({
      url: "genformexec.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  formDat,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(data) {
          $('.logresult').html(data);
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
  return false;




  </script>
```

And lose one of these : `<input type="file" onchange="logo_prev()" name="profimages" id="profimages">` `<input type="file" name="profimages" id="profimages">` Id should be unique

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#genreg').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = new FormData(this);
  data.append( 'profimages1', $( '#profimages1' )[0].files[0] ); // change profimages as profimages1
  data.append( 'coverimage', $( '#coverimage' )[0].files[0] );
  data.append( 'profimages2', $( '#profimages2' )[0].files[0] ); // change profimages as profimages2

  var ccode = $('#ccode').val();
  var fname = $('#fname').val();
  var lname = $('#lname').val();
  var cname = $('#cname').val();
  var crnum = $('#crcnum').val();
  var uaddress = $('#uaddress').val();
  var caddress = $('#caddress').val();
  var briefdes = $('#briefdes').val();
  var uname = $('#uname').val();
  var uphone = $('#uphone').val();
  var pword = $('#pword').val();
  var cfpword = $('#cfpword').val();
  var posttype = $("input[name=postValue]").each($(this)).val();
  $.ajax({
      url: "genformexec.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  data,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(data) {
          $('.logresult').html(data);
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
  return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also occur if you are trying to send files or post data with size being more than the allowed limit(default being 2MB).
You can try to increase the limit.Modify these values in **.htaccess** file as below.

**php_value post_max_size 5M**

**php_value upload_max_filesize 5M**